# Custom post type archive category page results in 404

Tags: categories, templates, custom-post-type-archives

I've created a custom post type:

```
register_post_type('campaign',
   array(
      'labels' => array(
         'name' => __("Campaigns"),
         'singular_name' => __("Campaign"),
      ),
      'rewrite' => array(
         'slug' => 'campaigns',
         'with_front' => FALSE,
      ),
      'public' => TRUE,
      'has_archive' => TRUE,
      'supports' => array('title', 'editor', 'thumbnail'),
      'publicly_queryable' => TRUE,
   )
);
```

And a custom taxonomy for categories:

```
register_taxonomy( 'campaign_category', 'campaign', 
   array( 
      'hierarchical' => TRUE, 
      'label' => 'Categories', 
      'query_var' => TRUE, 
      'rewrite' => array(
          'slug' => 'category',
          'with_front' => FALSE,
          'hierarchical' => FALSE,
      ),
   ) 
);
```

Because the post type was created with `has_achive` set to `TRUE` I can browse to the `/campaigns` URL and my `archive-campaign.php` template is triggered. So far so good.

However, when I try to access a category, `/campaigns/category/fashion`, I get a `404`.

The category with the correct slug exists and I've re-saved my permalinks each time I've made a chance to any of the rewriting rules.

Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things:

1. You shouldn't be using 'category' as a slug, since it's already built into WP and thus is reserved (http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy#Reserved_Terms)
2. Pretending for a moment that it isn't reserved, the base URL structure wouldn't contain the post type in front of it.

EDIT

1. I just realized you didn't set the archive slug itself. Instead of `has_archive = true`, set it to `has_archive = 'campaigns'` (to match your other slug). That should set your permalinks to match.

Comment: Thanks! 1. I don't think the reservered terms apply to the slug, however, I've tried with another slug (categoryx), re-saved my permalinks, no joy. 2. I do not understand what you mean. Can you explain it differently?

Comment: WordPress does not auto-create rules that bind post types with taxonomies, they create one set of rules for each. Does that help clarify?

Comment: adding to what @t31os said, your example setup would create:

domain.com/campaign/post-slug
domain/com/category/fashion/post-slug

you would need to include some custom permalink re-writes. this post can give you a primer on it. http://shibashake.com/wordpress-theme/add-custom-taxonomy-tags-to-your-wordpress-permalinks

Comment: @Norcross; Thanks for that link. I have a read through that. What you're saying is not entirely correct. I can happily browse to /campaigns/post-slug whereas /campaign/post-slug fails. Pagination on these archives are working fine, so why aren't categories? Would it be possible for you to update your answer and elaborate on 2. rather than adding comments?

Comment: @Norcross; Thanks heaps! Your EDIT put me on the right track. I do not have to create a dummy page anymore for '/campaigns' and all templates are working correctly now!

Answer (score 0):

You have to se up your taxonomy slug as "%campaign_category%" and replace it in a function later.

Here I explain how I did it (I applied it to the category itself because I wanted to also delete the category slug from the url, but will understand)

[Removed slug from CPT, now How/where do I hook the filter to the taxonomy term archive pages link?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/57250/removed-slug-from-cpt-now-how-where-do-i-hook-the-filter-to-the-taxonomy-term-a)

Let me know if your different case breaks the other links too. This solutions worked for others but I think it breaks in my site because some other reasons, e.g. multisite installation.